# Does DB2 accept SSL3 connections?

Tags: security, ssl, db2, poodle

Does DB2 allow connection through Secure Sockets Layer version 3 (SSL3)?
To be more exact, will a program using SSL3 connection get an access to DB2? or will it fail?

If it does accept it, is there away to disable it?

Comment: Do not cross-post questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531222/how-can-i-disable-ssl3-on-db2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the following:

DB2 server has disabled SSL V3 support since DB2 V9.5 FP3 and therefore it is not possible to connect to DB2 using the  SSL V3 protocol.

DB2 version before 9.5 are out of service starting April 30 2012. More info on [supported DB2 versions here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21168270).